# Display JSON DATA in dataGridView

Tags: c#, json, api

I want to display JSON data in DGview in c#

I tried 2 codes works with  Newtonsoft.Json
but both of them shows error invalid input but input is correct as I know

this is an input

https://dastanito.ir/test/ex2/api/storiesmaster/read.php

```cs
{"StoriesMasters":[{"id":"4545","story_code":"xv35454","master_code":"mvm,454"},{"id":"2","story_code":"002a","master_code":"he3385_1"},{"id":"60","story_code":"001a","master_code":"he3385_1"},{"id":"3","story_code":"c57675","master_code":"ara3433_2"},{"id":"45","story_code":"hdgw878","master_code":"f998989d"},{"id":"50","story_code":"d8885","master_code":"za76787_3"}]}
```

this is the first code I used:

```cs
using Newtonsoft;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

void get_response()
{
     WebClient wp = new WebClient();
     string url = "http://dastanito.ir/test/ex2/api/storiesmaster/read.php";
     var response=wp.DownloadString(url);
     get_data(response);
}

void get_data(string response)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    JArray fetch= JArray.Parse(response);
    if(fetch.Count()>0)
    {
        for(int i=0;dataGridView1.Rows.Count>i;i++)
        {
            int n=dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value=fetch[i]["JsonObjectName1"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and the other one is :

```cs
using RestSharp;

using Newtonsoft;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

  public class JsonResult
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string story_code { get; set; }
            public int master_code { get; set; }

        }


void getdata()
{
     var client = new RestClient("http://dastanito.ir");

            var request = new RestRequest("test/ex2/api/storiesmaster/read.php", Method.GET);

            // execute the request
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;
            richTextBox1.Text = response.Content;

         var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult>(content);
          dataGridView1.DataSource = result;

}
```

and the ERROR IS
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Rmb.jpg)

Comment: Can you share a small part if sample json too? You need to create a class to which the json can be deserialize to. Then use newtonsoft to deserialize json to collection of that class objects and then bind the grid view to the collection

Comment: HI @ChetanRanpariya, yes i did it in the second code ' class JsonResult ' but it returns error that i linked about invalid input . i shared sample json it is here : dastanito.ir/test/ex2/api/storiesmaster/read.php sorry if i did not understand well what did you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two classes as following.

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string story_code { get; set; }
    public string master_code { get; set; }
}

public class DataList
{
    public List<Data>  StoriesMasters { get; set; }
}
```

now you can deserialize the json to an object of DataList class as following.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataList>(content);
```

And now you can bind `StoriesMasters` property to grid view.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = result.StoriesMasters;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json entry entity is object, not array. Array starts with [ ] and object starts with { } brackets.

Change `JArray fetch = JArray.Parse(response);` to `JObject fetch = JObject.Parse(response);`

Comment: hi @suxrobgm@SuxrobGM thanks for that help, what about rest of the code it is not an array so i can not count and how can i use it?

Comment: See above answer. You need classes to map json objects. Create classes then deserialize it